How to preview composable function with MutableSharedFlow<T> as a parameter?
I have a funtion like this but I cannot preview it:
data class ViewEffect(
    val error: String? = null,
)

@Composable
fun EditContactInfoScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mutableSharedFlow: MutableSharedFlow<ViewEffect>,
) {
    
}


Don't pass flows to a composable. Parameters to composables should only be simple, stable/immutable objects like data classes.
Instead collect the flow as soon as you retrieve it and only pass the collected value on to other composables. Assuming there is an EditContactInfoScreen that calls EditContactInfoScreenContent it could look something like this:
@Composable
fun EditContactInfoScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val mutableSharedFlow: MutableSharedFlow<ViewEffect> = TODO()
    val viewEffect by mutableSharedFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(ViewEffect())

    EditContactInfoScreenContent(
        modifier = modifier,
        viewEffect = viewEffect,
    )
}

@Composable
fun EditContactInfoScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewEffect: ViewEffect,
) {

}

This also allows you to easily create a preview:
@Preview
@Composable
fun EditContactInfoScreenContentPreview() {
    EditContactInfoScreenContent(viewEffect = ViewEffect())
}

